# Given two distinct primes $p,q$ such that $(p-1)(q-1)=A$, are $p$ and $q$ uniquely determined by $A$?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, prime-numbers, prime-factorization

I believe another way I could phrase the question is:

Given $f(m,n)\equiv(m-1)(n-1)$ where $m$ and $n$ are two primes:

Is $f$ one-to-one for pairings of $(m,n)$?

---

Or:

Are there only two distinct primes $(p,q)$ which make $f=A$?

---

I conjecture the answer is yes, there is only one pairing which exists for each output, but I can still somewhat envision there being some way to get non-distinct mappings from $A\to(m,n)$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, for example for $A=72$, the equation $(p-1)(q-1)=A$ has $4$ prime solutions:
$$(p,q)\in\{ (2, 73),(3, 37), (5, 19), (7,13)\}.$$
For $A=1080$ there are $6$ prime solutions:
$$(p,q)\in\{ (3, 541), (5, 271), (7,181), (11,109), (19,61), (31,37)\}.$$

Answer (score 1):

If I understood that question correctly.

No, since: 
\begin{align*}(7-1)(13-1) = 6\cdot12&=72 \\
(3-1)(37-1) = 2\cdot 36 &= 72
\end{align*}

and $3, 7, 13, 37$ are prime.

Comment: Overseen the "distinct". Corrected the example according.

Answer (score -1):

It's quite easy to hunt for counter examples. For example

Consider the factors of $36$.
\begin{array}{rr|rr}
p-1 & q-1 & p & q \\
\hline
1   &  36 & 2 & 37 \\
2   &  18 & 3 & 19 \\
3   &  12 \\
4   &   9 \\
6   &   6 & 7 & 7 \\
\hline
\end{array}

So $f(2,37)=f(3,19)=36$.

Consider the factors of $60$.
\begin{array}{rr|rr}
p-1 & q-1 & p & q \\
\hline
1   &  60 & 2 & 61 \\
2   &  30 & 3 & 31 \\
3   &  20 \\
4   &  12 & 5 & 13\\
6   &  10 & 7 & 11 \\
\hline
\end{array}

So $f(2,61)=f(3,31)=f(5,13)=f(7,11)=60$.